# WHY do waves diffract - what is the mechanism behind the diffraction?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

Having recently studied wave diffraction at an introductory level, I don't feel that I understand why waves diffract like they do.

What is it about the obstacle or the waves interaction with it which causes the object to diffract?

Is a wave many single points which can 'break out' once unrestricted by the part of the wave which once travelled along side it?

So I understand how waves behave when they diffract and the relationships between wavelength and the gap through which it travels, but I don't understand **why**.

All Google searches seem to lead me to articles that explain how the wave behaves and not the why.

Comment: Maybe Im oversimplifying the picture, but IMHO the **how** *is* the **why**...

Comment: I've edited that 'how' to 'how the wave behaves'. So I understand how the wave will behave, but what is the mechanism that causes the diffraction to occur?

Comment: maybe what you want is a description of the phenomenon at molecular level? Is that right? Anyway, welcome to physics.SE!

Comment: Some people would say that any question which start with the word "Why" cannot be answered within the umbrella of science.

Comment: @AccientalFourierTransform - Thanks and yes that is a good summary of what I'm asking. Is there such an explanation?

Comment: @Farcher - thanks, may be this is something I will have to get used to!

Comment: The ideal plane wave has an infinite range of frequencies transverse to the wave (along that perfect wave front) - it is infinite in width. Encountering an obstacle or aperture acts as a filter and removes some of those frequency components. Clearly, the perfect wavefront can no longer remain perfect without all the Fourier frequencies, and the resulting response is what we call diffraction.

Comment: @Jon Custer - thank you, your comment seems to hit at what I'm asking. I will investigate some of the terms you have used and hopefully improve my understanding.

Comment: The animated pictures in this article might help:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction#Single-slit_diffraction  Just imagine that you're looking down on ocean waves impinging on an opening in a sea wall.

Comment: A wave is something that obeys a wave equation. That's it.

Comment: @CuriousOne. Surely it is the wave equation which a lot of the time allows us to predict what a wave will do?

Comment: @Jon Custer Is it a pulse that you are writing about?

Comment: @Farcher: It's the usual chicken and egg problem. What is a force? A force is that which is defined by Newton's second law. Sounds trivial, right? But if you think about it, that's how you do things in physics. You name a phenomenon and you give a description for it that defines it as well as possible. So what's a wave? It's something that obeys, with some reasonable approximation, a wave equation. The equation is what describes diffraction and other phenomena in detail, it's the short form of the "how" and, to whatever limited extent possible in science, also the "why".

Comment: The Huygens-Fresnel principle seemed to be the closest explanation of the 'mechanism' of a wave. The following paragraph helped to capture it's limitations for me: "The Huygens–Fresnel principle provides a good basis for understanding and predicting the wave propagation of light. However, there are limitations to the principle and differing views as to whether it is an accurate representation of reality or whether "Huygens' principle actually does give the right answer but for the wrong reasons"